# How to play YouTube videos in 240 by default

Tags: video, youtube

I have a slow internet connection and I changed the setting in YouTube to "I have a slow connection and never play HD video". Even so, it starts loading the video in 360, so that every time I need to change it to 240. I tried setting even auto, but it keeps getting pauses.

Is there anyway to change it to 240 permanently?

Answer (score 1):

To change the setting fort this, follow the steps below:

1. Go to your **Settings** page.
2. Click the **Playback Settings** link.
3. Choose between the default setting and the “I have a slow connection” setting.
4. Click the **Save Settings** button.

Comment: yes I did that: I have a slow connection. Never play higher-quality video. But even so it plays video in 360

Answer (score 1):

I use the "Turn Off the Lights" browser extension (Google Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Opera, Microsoft Edge, Maxthon and Yandex web browser). In the option page you can choose the quality of the YouTube video to 144p or even 4K (ultra HD)

You can download on either website:

- https://www.turnoffthelights.com
- https://www.stefanvd.net

Answer (score 1):

Use the **[Improve YouTube!](https://improvedtube.com/)** browser extension: [Chrome version](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/improve-youtube-video-you/bnomihfieiccainjcjblhegjgglakjdd/) / [Firefox version](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/youtube-addon/).

Once installed, click on the extension's button → Player → Quality → 240p to configure it to play videos in 240p by default. (You can also configure it to use other resolutions by default.) Settings screenshot:

[image: screenshot of above-described setting]

Answer (score 0):

You can try using browser extensions. For example, Magic Actions For YouTube allows this (https://www.mycinema.pro/)

This extension is available for: Google Chrome, Firefox, Opera.